# JPA Annotations - How to retrieve all entities with a specific column value

Tags: jpa, annotations, one-to-many, identity-column

Let say I have an entity object Customer with an "OneToMany" relation to Order. I want that when ever a "Customer" get loaded, only his orders with the Id = 1234, 5678 get loaded to.

Any ideas?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Customer")
public class Customer extends TraceableJPA {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = "customer_id")
        private Long id;

        @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "Customer", targetEntity = Order.class)
        @Column(name = "order_id", value = {"1234","5678"} (?))
        @OrderBy("isrtdate ASC")
        @BatchSize(size = 20)
        private List<Order> orders = new ArrayList<Order>();
```

Comment: You can't do that. If a `Customer` has some orders that meet your filter and has some that don't ... then tough luck, you get all that pertain to that `Customer`. The javadocs for the `@Column` annotation says clear enough what it allows and what it is for.

Comment: I ain't asking to use @Column. It was just an example. Feel free to suggest an other @... It just wanna be able to filter the contain of this variable, as long as the orders to checkout are precisely known.

Comment: "You can't do that". Can't really get more definitive ...

Answer (score 0):

### Hibernate

If you use hibernate Session and its abilites , you can always use **@FilterJoinTable** mechanism.

Check [THIS](https://www.concretepage.com/hibernate/hibernate-filter-and-filterjointable-annotation-example) article for more information.

Yet it is not global, you have to predefine this filter and then explicitly configure Session object to use it.

### JPA

JPA in its standard has NO SUCH FUNCTIONALITY, for global relations filtering.

You can always filter it in your queries : )